# Retention Policy on SharePoint 2010 as "Move to another Place"

Tags: 2010, list, document-library, retention, information-policy

I have to apply Retention Policy to all Documents and list contents. The condition for the policy is that documents and list data older than 3 years move to another location. This location should be accessible with all moved data.

Please suggest the steps.

Answer (score 0):

As the Created column cannot be used for site content types Document and Item in the Retention Policy, so you need to create another date column in the Document or Item content type and use a workflow or event receiver to update the new date column with Created column value when uploading a new document or creating a list item.

After that you can use the new date column to set the time period in the Retention Policy for the site content types Document and Item.

Reference:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2011/10/12/policy-and-retention-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx

Comment: An additional word of warning... DONT apply a retention policy on Document content type. Always apply it on your custom content type. Document is used by css files and master pages (and a lot more) and moving/deleting them is creating a suicidal SharePoint!